# Haskell filtered string to list

Tags: string, list, haskell, filter

I want a fuction where you put in a String like "Hello I am 25 years old!" and get a list out of it like ["hello","i","am","years","old"]. So it should put all uppercase letters in lowercase and delete everything that isnt a letter. It should just use Data.List and Data.Char.
I know i should use words on the String and then filter it but i just cant figure it out (yes im new to Haskell).

```
toString :: String -> [String]
toString str = ...
```

Comment: Something like `filter (not . null) . map (filter Data.Char.isLower . map Data.Char.toLower) . words`. Think of it as three stages written right-to-left: break on spaces, within each word, convert to lower and prune out extras, then finally eliminate the empty words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my workflow: Use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and work with the type signatures you need.

1. On how to get a list of words: You need a function `foo` that does "one two three" -> ["one", "two", "three"] so it has the type signature: `String -> [String]`. Search for exactly this type signature via hoogle and you will find the function `words` second in the result list.
2. a method which does uppercase would mostly like have the type signature `Char -> Char`. Type this into hoogle and you will find `toUpper` in third in the list.
3. is a letter: Char -> Bool
4. next open ghci and try out the functions. IE:

   `ghci> :t toUpper -- will print the type of isUpper`

   `<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: ‘isUpper’` -- you need to import Data.Char

   `ghci> import Data.Char` -- so let´s import Data.Char

   `ghci> toUpper "abc"`

   `ghci> words "a quick brown fox"`

   `ghci> :t map`

   `ghci> map toUpper ["a", "quick"]`

... and so on

You`ll still need to figure out how to put these parts together with map and filter but again I´d advice you to have a close look at the types.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of answering a homework question:

```
import Data.Char

toString :: String -> [String]
toString str = filter (not . null) . map (map toLower . filter isAlpha) . words $ str

Prelude Data.Char> toString "Hello I am 25 years old!"
["hello", "i", "am", "years", "old"]
```

Comment: Had this before but I got this error so i opened this question

Couldn't match expected type `[String]'
            with actual type `String -> [[Char]]'
In the expression:
  filter (not . null) . map (map toLower . filter isAlpha) . words
In an equation for `getWords':
    getWords str
      = filter (not . null) . map (map toLower . filter isAlpha) . words

Comment: If you define the `str` argument in your function definition, then you also need to pass it to the function implementation. It should be either `getWords str = ... str` or `getWords = ...`